Error: Attempt to convert a value PIL to a Tensor
I tried running this code :
     import tensorflow as tf
     from tensorflow import keras
     from keras.models import  load_model
     import streamlit as st
     import numpy as np 

     st.header('Image Classification Model')
     model = load_model('C:\\Users\\ajit7\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Major Project\\Image_classify.keras')
     data_cat = ['WithMask', 'WithoutMask']
     img_height = 224
     img_width = 224
     image =st.text_input('Enter Image name','C:\\Users\\ajit7\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Major        Project\\gayatri-malhotra-26SGAduvONc-unsplash.png')

     image_load = tf.keras.utils.load_img(image, target_size=(img_height,img_width))
     img_arr = tf.keras.utils.array_to_img(image_load)
     img_bat=tf.expand_dims(img_arr,0)

     predict = model.predict(img_bat)

     score = tf.nn.softmax(predict)
     st.image(image, width=200)
     st.write(  data_cat[np.argmax(score)])
     st.write('With accuracy of ' + str(np.max(score)*100))`

I was expecting to get if info based on the prediction of model I used but instead I got this :
    ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=224x224 at 0x213D2F9E670>) with an unsupported type (<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>) to a Tensor.
    Traceback:
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 584, in _run_script
        exec(code, module.__dict__)
    File "C:\Users\ajit7\OneDrive\Documents\Major Project\app1.py", line 17, in <module>
        img_bat=tf.expand_dims(img_arr,0)
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
        return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)


Why do you convert the array to an image if you're going to be using it as an array?

Too many factors here, it might be incorrect path, unsupported image format. But I would advise perhaps trying this:
Replace:
img_arr = tf.keras.utils.array_to_img(image_load)
img_bat = tf.expand_dims(img_arr, 0)

With:
img_arr = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image_load)
img_bat = tf.expand_dims(img_arr, 0) / 255.0

